# UITapGestureRecognizer not picking up inputs on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, tvos

I'm working on a small SpriteKit game for tvOS. I need to receive input when the user clicks the play/pause button on the remote. Looking at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html), it appears that I should just have to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to my scene's view. I implemented the following code:

```swift
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let tapPlayPause = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTesting))
    tapPlayPause.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.playPause.rawValue)]
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapPlayPause)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeUp))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
}

@objc func tapTesting(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("TAP")
}
```

However, when I run the app on my Apple TV 4K (running tvOS 15), there is no output and from what I can tell no tap code is getting triggered.

I have tried the code with `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` as well but I still do not receive tap inputs.

The swipe gesture I implemented above works perfectly thought, and the tap gesture works on my iOS devices. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: When are you tapping a view controller's view or whatever?  After switching to a game scene?  If that's the case, view controller's view isn't accessible.

Comment: @El Tomato, just curious are taps handled differently then swipes? If not, why would swipes work and not taps? Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer that.  And I don't even know under which class you are writing those lines of code.

Comment: It’s in my GameScene (which is just a subclass of SKScene), which I load via a SwiftUI SpriteView. Also if the view controller’s view isn’t accessible, wouldn’t that cause the same issue on iOS as tvOS? Just curious because the UITapGestureRecognizers works as expected on iOS devices. Let me know if there’s any extra code/info I can post that would be useful.

Comment: You don't use `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `SKScene`.  Using a tap gesture is pretty much the same as using a UIButton over `SKScene`.  If you want to make a tap action, use `UIEvent` like `UITouch` instead.  And don't use a `UIButton` over `SKScene`.  We use an `SKNode` instead.

Comment: I’ll give that a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For tvOS gestures, you also need to set `allowedTouchTypes` to `.indirect`

```swift
tapPlayPause.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(touchType: .indirect)]
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm still having the issue. I tried setting it explicitly: `tapPlayPause.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]`, but according to the docs "The default value of this property contains all touch types." So would this actually make a difference? Also it sounds like this is for touches rather than button presses. Thanks for suggesting though!